# It is possible to extend classes that uses Builder pattern and private constructor?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have a lame test classes named Box and PackageBox.
Box uses Builder Pattern and PackageBox that supposed to extend Box

Here is some code

```
package console.app.model;

public class Box {

private String name = "";
private int weight = 0;
private int width = 0;
private int height = 0;

// Box instance for comparison on method equals().
private static Box comparisonBox;

public static class Builder {

    private String name = "";
    private int weight = 0;
    private int width = 0;
    private int height = 0;

    public Builder(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Builder weight(int weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder width(int width) {
        this.width = width;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder height(int height) {
        this.height = height;
        return this;
    }

    public Box build() {
        return new Box(this);
    }

}

private Box(Builder builder) {
    name = builder.name;
    weight = builder.weight;
    width = builder.width;
    height = builder.height;
}

    // Setters and getters, etc.
```

}

How can I extend Box to PackageBox?
Thank you, and if something is wrong please tell me or something to replace in Box class.

Comment: If it's a pain to extend, rewrite it so it's easy.

Comment: If someone else wrote `Box`, they may be deliberately trying to prevent subclassing.

Comment: @Bohemian, I know that but I'm looking for a way to do this.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask the original author how this was meant to be done.  Generally, restrictions like this are there for a reason.

Comment: That's one of the example in Effective Java book and the book didn't said that it is supposed to prevent subclassing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a protected constructor to Box and then subclass it, calling the protected constructor from the PackageBox constructor. However, you will need to implement a new Builder for PackageBox if you want to go that route.